# remove_action on related products is not working with woocommerce hook

Tags: woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
```

I have this line in my `functions.php` file. I got these hooks from the `content-single-product.php` file. However, the related products on my single product page still exists.

I don't want to remove the functionality entirely, I duped their `$args` to do my own query.

**Updated**

```
function remove_woo_relate_products(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );
}

add_action('init', 'remove_woo_relate_products', 10);
```

I tried to write a function to achieve my goal, but the related products from the `do_action` is still present. I can only think of CSS to do what I need, but I shouldn't have to rely on this.

Also, just for the sake of showing this, this is what's in the `content-single.product.php` file:

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
?>
```

Comment: The priority in your remove statement does not match the priority of the `add_action()`, which is 10.

Comment: **The code you are using works perfectly** (and the **priorities** you are using **are the good ones**). Your issue is certainly related to your theme. To illustrate this evidence, Try the following (making a database backup before): Switch to default Wordpress theme and add your code to the function.php of this default theme and save. **You will see that your code is working…**

Answer (score 4):

As [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec) correctly pointed out, your code is working fine. We tested it. The related products were removed but the upsell products were still there.
We tested using storefront theme.

```
function remove_woo_relate_products(){  
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'storefront_upsell_display', 15 );
}
add_action('init', 'remove_woo_relate_products', 10);
```

You can see that `storefront_upsell_display` is calling the `woocommerce_upsell_display`

```
function storefront_upsell_display() {
    woocommerce_upsell_display( -1, 3 );
}
```

So in this code, we have removed the theme's action for upsell. In the same logic, there is a possibility that related products function may be called in your theme. If this is the case you can remove the corresponding action for that.

Note: Make sure the code is in your current theme's functions.php